# Como manter a tela ligada em versões posteriores a API do kitkat?

Tags: java, android

Estou fazendo um `APP` que **mantem a tela do smartphone sempre acesa**, mesmo quando o `APP` é minimizado.

Estou utilizando uma classe com `extends Service` para fazer isso, na onCreate coloco o código que mantem a tela sempre acesa:

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK, "watever");
    wl.acquire();
```

Android Studio me da um alerta: **FULL_WAKE_LOCK is deprecated**, mas não consegui descobrir como fazer na forma atual.

Este código só está funcionando até a **KitKat**.
Na **Lollipop** ou posterior, ele não apresenta erro algum, porem não funciona.

Exemplo de app que faz tela ficar acesa mesmo com o app fechado: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.brilliant.apps.screenon

Comment: Fiquei curioso de pq precisar manter a tela ligada de dentro de um `Service`, precisaria mesmo? Apenas manter a CPU ativa usando um `PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK` não resolveria?

Comment: O objetivo é fazer com que o usuário deixe a tela do smartphone sempre acesa, usando este recurso com o aplicativo minimizado ou fechado. Se souberem uma forma sem utilizar a Service pode ser também. Mas ele tem que conseguir usar esse recurso com o APP minimizado ou fechado.

Comment: Com a Service, o usuário consegue usar o recurso de tela acesa mesmo fechando o APP, os aplicativos existentes hoje na Google Play fazem desta forma como este por exemplo: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.brilliant.apps.screenon

Answer (score 2):

Atualmente você informa isso no layout, ou pelo XML ou programaticamente.

Programaticamente seria adicionar isso ao onCreate:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

no xml é só inserir no layout raiz o seguinte.

```
android:keepScreenOn="true"
```

Comment: Obrigado pela sugestão. Mas estou fazendo tudo em java, o usuário mesmo minimizando o app, ele continua ativo. Não aceita getWindow na onCreate da Service.

Comment: Verificando aqui, utilizei essa função numa aplicação aqui, era para funcionar corretamente :(

Comment: O problema @Shogogan, é que ele fazer isso num `Service`, mas o ideal dessa solução é ser feita numa `Activity`, por causa da `Window`.

Comment: entendi agora, perdão o mal entendimento da questão

Comment: Meu objetivo é fazer com que o usuário deixe a tela do smartphone sempre acesa, mesmo quando esta fora do aplicativo. se souberem uma forma sem utilizar a Service agradeço.

Mas ele tem que usar esse recurso com o APP minimizado. :)

Comment: olhando na documentação, eles substituiram o `FULL_WAKE_LOCK` pelo `FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON`, não encontrei uma maneira de utilizar fora isso, e agora fiquei curioso também para se existe uma maneira